# Using Azure Functions to copy indexes of Azure Search

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cognitive-search

I am currently following this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/azure-search-dotnet-samples/azure-search-backup-restore-index/ to copy indexes from one search service to another. The code works locally but is there anyway we can integrate the code within the document with Azure Functions.

Comment: Yes you can, however if you have large indexes, chances are you will face timeouts

Comment: if you want to keep two different indexes in sync, you'd better implement the logic to whenever you change a document on index A, you also implement it on B